# Does someone know if there is a known LibreOffice Impress API for reading and rendering presentation files?

Tags: javascript, c++, web, libreoffice

I am in the process of researching LibreOffice APIs for rendering ppt and pptx files but most of the documentation only offers controlling the libreoffice package itself in a headless mode. My view is I will be trying to create an app where it can read and render presentation files even if LibreOffice Impress is not installed in the machine.

Comment: how do you expect to be able to use libreoffice if it isn't installed?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, yes that's the point. I just wanted to use the libreoffice's selected feature without having it installed. More likely incorporating Impress to my own app and not only controlling it via headless mode.

Comment: you could use a portable version: https://www.libreoffice.org/download/portable-versions/

Comment: @AlanBirtles, seems not fully portable at all and based on the startup sequence the portable one will be harder to control as you have to set some options over and over again.

Comment: Well, take portable and wrap it up in a script

Comment: @Severin Papadeux, using portable isn't an option for now. I've already tried that and it will not be cross-platform. I've also seen some rendering issues with the portable version. Thanks